# How to create a jQuery button with blinking text without changing the background colour?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link and I would like the text contained in that link to blink (continuously) using jQuery.

```
<a href="#" class="blink">Button</a>
```

This is what I've got:

```
$(function() {

  blinking($(".blink"));

});

function blinking(elm) {
    timer = setInterval(blink, 10000);
    function blink() {
        elm.fadeOut(5000, function() {
        elm.fadeIn(5000);
    });
    }
}
```

It works but it fades out both the link text *and* the link's background colour.

This is my css:

```
.blink {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

How can I get it to fade in/out the text only?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I made a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97R5n/) for you and the text blinks fine in Chrome

Comment: Post your CSS for your `a` tag.  You stated it fades out the background; if you have background on the `a` it will fade that as well, as you are fading the whole element.

Comment: 90'th called. They want their webpages back.

Comment: What's the (intended) point of using `setInterval` every 10ms when your fades are at 5s? Also why don't use recursion from the 2nd callback and skip the interval?

Comment: @mishik I didn't get that at all?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I fixed some issues, however the main problem is still that both the background and the text colour get faded: http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/2/

Comment: @Connor, I would call you lucky for that. [blink tag story](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag)

Comment: Oh, the css blink thing, yeah i get it now....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have to call the animated function again after it has completed, like this.

```
var blink = function() {
    $('a').animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '1'
        }, blink);
    });
}

blink();
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/1/)

---

If you don't want the background color to fade you may have to use a bit of css like this.

**CSS:**

```
a{
    transition: color 200ms ease;
    background:skyblue;
}

a.blink{
    color:transparent;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('a').toggleClass('blink');
}, 500);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/4/)

Comment: This seems like the closest to what OP asked for +1

Comment: I'm afraid not because the background colour also fades: http://jsfiddle.net/p23zn/3/

Comment: Nice compact solution.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I stop blinking?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am assuming you have a background color on the `a` element.  So to fix that from blinking out you can simply put the text in a span and blink that:

HTML

```
<a href="#"><span class="blink">Button</span></a>
```

CSS

```
a 
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    blinking($(".blink"));

})($);

function blinking(elm) {
    timer = setInterval(blink, 10000);
    blink();

    function blink() {
        elm.fadeOut(5000, function () {
            elm.fadeIn(5000);
        });
    }
}
```

Also, `setInterval` uses milliseconds, not seconds.  So you should either change that to be 10000 as your delay or just call the blink method when the `fadeIn` is done.

http://jsfiddle.net/97R5n/3/

Comment: Thanks, I've already come across another answer stating the same. In my case I can't change the markup of the links, though. So I can't add any `span`s.

Comment: There's always JavaScript to do that if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function textblink() { $('.blink').toggle(); } setInterval(textblink, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id=blink>How to create blinking text with jQuery?</div>
```

jquery

```
function blink(e){
     $(e).fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
              blink(this);
          });
     });
}

blink('#blink');
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/7U3kc/

Comment: Thanks but this does exactly what my function does. It fades the background colour of my link as well. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This one initiate blinking without fading and also works on IE

```
function blinker(e)
{ $(e).delay( 250 ).fadeTo(0, 0, function()
    { if ($.browser.msie) $(this).css({'visibility':'hidden'})
      $(this).delay( 250 ).fadeTo(0, 1, function()
      { if ($.browser.msie) $(this).css({'visibility':'visible'})
        blinker(this);
      });
    });
}
blinker('#blinker')
```

This one initiate 3 blinks, it can be used on multiple elements simultaneously without conflicts

```
function blinker(e)
{ var e_id=$(e)[0].id
  window["blinker_counter_"+e_id]=0
  window["blinker_count_"+e_id]=3            //Times to blink
  blink(e)
}

function blink(e)
{ var e_id=$(e)[0].id
  $(e).delay( 250 ).fadeTo(0, 0, function()
    { if ($.browser.msie) $(this).css({'visibility':'hidden'})
      $(this).delay( 250 ).fadeTo(0, 1, function()
      { window["blinker_counter_"+e_id]++
        if ($.browser.msie) $(this).css({'visibility':'visible'})
        if (window["blinker_counter_"+e_id]<window["blinker_count_"+e_id])
        { blink(this);
        } else
        { window["blinker_counter_"+e_id]=undefined
          window["blinker_count_"+e_id]=undefined
        }

      });
    });
}
blinker('#blinker')
```