# Appearing/disappearing caption every 5 seconds in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, caption

For a very specific project, I need my image captions to appear AND Disappear every X seconds. I managed to make them appear and disappear once, but I need to to "loop". Here's my code :

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://url/image.jpg" alt="Write your image description here" width="400" height="600">
  <figcaption class="test">Write your image caption here!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Jquery :

```
document.createElement('figure');
document.createElement('figcaption');

window.setInterval(function(){$(document).ready(function(){
  $('figcaption').css('top','600px');
  $('figure')(function(){
  $(this).find('figcaption').animate({'top':'600px'}, 2000, function(){});
},function(){
  $(this).find('figcaption').animate({'top':'540px'}, 2000, function(){});
}
             );
});

}, 500);
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks (a lot) in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  $('figcaption').slideToggle();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <img src="http://url/image.jpg" alt="Write your image description here" width="50" height="50">
  <figcaption class="test">Write your image caption here!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('figcaption').fadeToggle(); 
}, 5000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02hgnef5/2/)

---

**EDIT**

Updated the fiddle to match your markup.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly want to do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var figcaption = $('figcaption');

    setInterval(function() {
        figcaption.hide().delay(5000).show();
    }, 10000);
});​
```

or:

```
document.createElement('figure');
document.createElement('figcaption');

$(document).ready(function() {
    var figcaption = $('figcaption');

    figcaption.css('top', '600px');

    window.setInterval(function() {
        figcaption
            .animate({'top':'600px'}, 2000)
            .delay(3000)
            .animate({'top':'540px'}, 2000)
        ;
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you attach a new method to the document load event every half second. Instead, initialize the interval only once on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $('figcaption').css('top','600px');

    // This call below seems a bit weird. Not sure what you try to accomplish
    $('figure')(
      function(){
        $(this).find('figcaption').animate({'top':'600px'}, 2000, function(){});
      },
      function(){
        $(this).find('figcaption').animate({'top':'540px'}, 2000, function(){});
      }
    );

  }, 500);
});
```

I'm not to sure about the code inside that function, but without more context I find it a bit hard to judge whether that will work or not.

Instead of hiding it completely through JavaScript, you can define a transition in CSS as well. You can call `toggleClass` to add and remove a CSS class to the element, or you can even define an infinite animation in CSS itself. This technique is asked for and demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578800/how-can-i-create-a-looping-fade-in-out-image-effect-using-css-3-transitions).

Answer (score 0):

This is the function can do more than you expected:

```
function blink(elem, times, speed) {
    if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
        if ($(elem).hasClass("blink")) $(elem).removeClass("blink");
        else $(elem).addClass("blink");
    }

    clearTimeout(function () {
        blink(elem, times, speed);
    });

    if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blink(elem, times, speed);
        }, speed);
        times -= .5;
    }
}
```

And you can use it as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
blink(".test", 4, 500);
});
```

See complete JSFiddle in: http://jsfiddle.net/jadendreamer/Nx4qS/

Hope this help.

**Edit**:

For using animate function see this post: [How to create a jQuery button with blinking text without changing the background colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910475/how-to-create-a-jquery-button-with-blinking-text-without-changing-the-background)